# Reshaping pandas data frame into as many columns as there are repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Place' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Var' : ['All', 'French', 'All', 'German', 'All', 'Spanish'], 'Values' : [250, 30, 120, 12, 200, 112]})

>> df
  Place  Values      Var
0     A     250      All
1     A      30   French
2     B     120      All
3     B      12   German
4     C     200      All
5     C     112  Spanish
```

It has a repeating pattern of two rows for every `Place`. I want to reshape it so it's one row per `Place` and the `Var` column becomes two columns, one for "All" and one for the other value.

Like so:

```
Place   All   Language   Value
    A   250     French      30
    B   120     German      12
    C   200     Spanish    112
```

A pivot table would make a column for each unique value, and I don't want that.

What's the reshaping method for this?

Answer (score 3):

Because the data appears in alternating pattern, we can conceptualize the transformation in 2 steps.

Step 1:

Go from

```
a,a,a
b,b,b
```

To

```
a,a,a,b,b,b
```

Step 2: drop redundant columns.

The following solution applies `reshape` to the `values` of the DataFrame; the arguments to reshape are `(-1, df.shape[1] * 2)`, which says 'give me a frame that has twice as many columns and as many rows as you can manage.

Then, I hardwired the column indexes for the filter: `[0, 1, 4, 5]` based on your data layout. Resulting `numpy` array has 4 columns, so we pass it into a `DataFrame` constructor along with the correct column names.

It is an unreadable solution that depends on the `df` layout and produces columns in the wrong order;

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Place' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Var' : ['All', 'French', 'All', 'German', 'All', 'Spanish'], 'Values' : [250, 30, 120, 12, 200, 112]})

df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, df.shape[1] * 2)[:,[0,1,4,5]],
    columns = ['Place', 'All', 'Value', 'Language'])
```

Comment: This works! But I don't quite understand how. Would you mind explaining your process?

Comment: Thanks for this. So -1 as an argument for `numpy.reshape` ensures the dimension is maintained no matter what the other argument is?

Comment: Yes, useful shorthand notation.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Place' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'Var' : ['All', 'French', 'All', 'German', 'All', 'Spanish'], 'Values' : [250, 30, 120, 12, 200, 112]})

df1 = df.set_index('Place').pivot(columns='Var')

df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()

df1 = df1.set_index('All', append=True).stack().reset_index()

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  Place    All      Var      0
0     A  250.0   French   30.0
1     B  120.0   German   12.0
2     C  200.0  Spanish  112.0
```

Comment: Really interesting solution. The use of `droplevel` and `stack` is clever.